# Memset or for loop to zero multiple same length arrays

Tags: c, memset

I have multiple same length arrays I wish to fill with zero's. Let's look at two ways of doing that:

### 1)

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<ARRAYSLENGTH;i++){
    arr1[i]=0;
    arr2[i]=0;
    arr3[i]=0;
    ...
}
```

### 2) `memset` all the arrays to zero.

In a recent code review I was asked to change option 1 to option 2. Which made me wonder, Which of these methods is better ? Mainly:

Is 2 considered more readable than 1?

How do these two methods compare in terms of efficiency ? (considering `memset` is usually implemented in assembly but method 1 only increments the counter once for multiple arrays).

Comment: Subjectively, yes, 2 is more readable and expresses your intent more clearly. Also, you probably realise this, but `memset` has some tricks up its sleeve that can make it faster than the naive one-by-one approach.

Comment: There is a third approach `A arr1[10] ={0};` It will set all the `10` elements to `0`.

Comment: If you combine them all into one two-dimensional array, you can get away with one call to `memset` or the simpler (IMO) `A arr[NUM_ARRAYS][ARRAY_LENGTH] = {{0}};`.

Comment: Note, though, that `memset` will only work when initializing with a constant stream of _bytes_ while the initialization syntax will only work when all unmentioned values are to be set to 0.  If/When you want to initialize to something else, the `for` loop will be your best bet.

Comment: Also, compilers have been known to optimize such `for` loops into calls to `memset`, so there may be no performance advantage whatsoever.  In that case you should prefer whichever version is clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method 1 (the `for` loop), is bad for the cache.

As `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3` may not be anywhere near each other in memory, and very likely will not be in the cache together, you could have frequent cache-misses, and the CPU will have to constantly fetch new pieces from memory, just to set them to zero.

By doing a set of `memset` operations, you'll hit **ALL** of `arr1`, at once, almost certainly entirely from the cache.  Then you'll cache and set all of `arr2` very quickly, etc, etc.

That, and because `memset` may well have assembly tricks and optimizations to make it faster, I would *definitely* prefer option 2 over option 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think most programmers should be able to read memset and know what it's doing so readability shouldn't be an issue.
With most modern compilers you probably wouldn't see much performance difference but I would use memset as that's what it's for.

Comment: I'd say that `memset` is more readable, because you don't have to read much to know what the code is doing. Having to read a for loop and understand what it's doing is more taxing (even if it's a simple loop).

Answer (score 0):

You can even use bzero instead of memset which is more specific